# Running 2 OS X’s Simultaneously on the Same Partition?

Tags: snow-leopard

I don’t know if this is the right thread section for this question but what I’m trying to do is something similar to Parallels but running 2 independent OS X platforms on the same partition.

I want to run an old legacy Snow Leopard and a High Sierra at the same time. But I don’t want to have to shut down the machine and with partitions to access the op systems.

Is there some type of program where I can just program a keyboard button or tap an icon to immediately switch over from one OS X to the next and the transition be quick and seamless?

Comment: The answer is use Parallels with a SnowLeopard Virtual Machine

Comment: What you want cannot be done other than with a virtual machine. You cannot run any macOS older than the Mac itself, so you'd need a Mac from around 2010 to be able to even run both those OSes, individually, in hardware.

Comment: The other program to create a virtual machine is VirtualBox and it's a free software.

Comment: yes I'm using a 2011 MBP for this so it will work with 10.6.8, but Parallels is for running Windows on a Mac and I want to run 2 OS X's in Parallels or VirtualBox or any other comparable program. Would this be possible?

Comment: Parallels or VMWare Fusion [avoid virtualbox, it's poor in comparison] can run **any** virtual machine so long as it can run on Intel. Strictly speaking 10.6.8 is not licensed for virtualisation unless you bought the server version, so you'll have to look round the interwebz for ways round that;) BTW, MBP early 2011 can run Snow Leo natively, Late 2011 can't.

Comment: You are in error. Virtualization software is for virtualizing **ANY** OS on any other OS. There are caveats but running Snow Leopard in a VM is a common task and should work fine on pretty much any Mac including the one you mentioned.

Comment: ok so I'm getting some conflicting info, I'm told that virtual can run on 2011 MBP SL and then that it can't, and is there a problem with the version of VirtualBox to be installed into Snow Leopard and the ability to have High Sierra or Mojave installed into that as a Guest OS, which version of VirtualBox or Parallels or VMWare Fusion can do that?

Comment: The info isn't conflicting, you're just not parsing it correctly. Install Parallels, Fusion or VB on your Mac running High Sierra. Install Snow Leo on a VM, if you can find a copy [you can trust] that can be virtualised. You can't get one from Apple unless you pay for the server version. Google "virtualise snow leopard" for workarounds.

Comment: I have a "regular" Snow Leopard copy, I would have preferred to have SL as my base op system with HS in the VM but that doesn't seem possible is what I'm seeing, I may opt for Mountain Lion as my base and install HS in the VM if that is a better fit perhaps?

Comment: what VirtualBox version works best for Mountain Lion to then install Capitan or any Sierra as the Guest OS into the VM?

Comment: It's always best to run the older OS in VM on the newer OS.